# Microsoft News Search API XML Response?

Tags: xml, api, azure-cognitive-services, azure-marketplace

I was using the older version of the Bing Search News API and have now been forced to move over to the new version 5 of the Azure Marketplace Search News API.

Prior to the move I had a system setup in my CMS to pull many bing news search by keyword queries each day and my system parsed the XML to get news title, publication, date, link, image etc.

Now with the new version of the API I only see that a JSON response comes back from the URL.  I need to be able to get a XML / RSS / ATOM etc type response back from the API with the results.

Is there anyway to send the query through URL to the API and get back a response in an XML / RSS / OR ATOM type format?

Here is my current call that is getting the JSON response:
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?q=sustainability&count=10&format=XML&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safeSearch=Moderate&Subscription-Key=XXXX

Is there something I can add to change the response from JSON to XML type response?

Answer (score 0):

The only response formats for V5 Bing Search -  Cognitive Services are JSON and JSON-LD.  XML is not available.